# minted or similar with URI instead of local

Tags: minted, code

Is it possible to pull code in via http from eg a public git repo using minted?

This question is motivated by the fact that direct integration between git remotes and overleaf seems to have [some limitations right now](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_do_I_connect_an_Overleaf_project_with_a_repo_on_GitHub,_GitLab_or_BitBucket%3F#:%7E:text=You%20can%20configure%20your%20Overleaf,Then%20follow%20the%20prompts.).

Comment: minted requires shell-escape and if you enable shell-escape you have full access to any commands that you have access to from the shell

Comment: Thanks, David.  Considering the possible intended/unintended results I'm shocked overleaf allows this:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_use_latexmkrc_with_Overleaf:_examples_and_techniques  

I'll try to whip up an mwe and post an answer accordingly.